# Error in XML file: cvc-elt.1.a Cannot find the declaration of element?

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xsd, xml-validation

Got this XML from PHP_Parser, but it's corrupted, when validating, got error: **cvc-elt.1.a: Cannot find the declaration of element 'AST'.**
What should i append to it?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AST xmlns:node = "http://nikic.github.com/PHPParser/XML/node"
     xmlns:subNode = "http://nikic.github.com/PHPParser/XML/subNode"
     xmlns:attribute = "http://nikic.github.com/PHPParser/XML/attribute"
     xmlns:scalar = "http://nikic.github.com/PHPParser/XML/scalar">
    <scalar:array>
        <node:Expr_Assign>
            <attribute:startLine>
                <scalar:int>3</scalar:int>
            </attribute:startLine>
            <attribute:endLine>
                <scalar:int>3</scalar:int>
            </attribute:endLine>
            <subNode:var>
                <node:Expr_Variable>
                    <attribute:startLine>
                        <scalar:int>3</scalar:int>
                    </attribute:startLine>
                    <attribute:endLine>
                        <scalar:int>3</scalar:int>
                    </attribute:endLine>
                    <subNode:name>
                        <scalar:string>user</scalar:string>
                    </subNode:name>
                </node:Expr_Variable>
            </subNode:var>
            <subNode:expr>
                <node:Scalar_LNumber>
                    <attribute:startLine>
                        <scalar:int>3</scalar:int>
                    </attribute:startLine>
                    <attribute:endLine>
                        <scalar:int>3</scalar:int>
                    </attribute:endLine>
                    <subNode:value>
                        <scalar:int>777</scalar:int>
                    </subNode:value>
                </node:Scalar_LNumber>
            </subNode:expr>
        </node:Expr_Assign>
    </scalar:array>
</AST>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that no (default) namespace is defined for element AST.

I would adapt the element AST so that a namespace is defined for it and in the output of PHP_Parser the element is prefixed with a namespace.